# random access aligned memory with SSE

Tags: c++, c, sse, simd

I try to write on a random positions in an int array. 
To be sure I can access the memory on a random position I tried to align the whole block of memory.

```
int * array = memalign(16384*2,16384*sizeof(short));
```

Later on I write in the vector like this:

```
__m128i * index = (__m128i *) &array[RANDOMNUMBER];
_mm_store_si128(index+, ...)
```

This instruction leads to an bad access. If I use the `_mm_storeu_si128` instruction I don't get it.
Can somebody explain me why this doesn't work?

Comment: Try align the write position.

Comment: how do I align the write position?

Comment: `_mm_store_si128( (index+RANDOMNUMBER) & ~(127), ...) `

Comment: @erenon thank you but if try to write this I get an error. "error: invalid operands of types '__m128i* {aka __vector(2) long long int*}' and 'int' to binary 'operator&". how can this logical operation align?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument for `_mm_store_si128` must be 16 byte-aligned. A randomly chosen element of an int-array will only be sizeof(int)-aligned (even if the array itself is 16 byte-aligned). So you must make sure that the index into the array is a multiple of `(16/sizeof(int))`, e.g. like so:

```
__m128i * index = (__m128i *) &array[(RANDOMNUMBER / (16/sizeof(int))) * (16/sizeof(int))];
```

This will guarantee that the write will be properly aligned. Whether this is what your code really needs to do is another question...

Comment: thank you. no the code is not what I want to archive. I really need the access on that certain position. I hoped this works because everything is aligned. I guess there is no code that can do what I want. So I have to use _mm_storeu_si128

Comment: yes, if you need to access that position, you need to use _mm_storeu_si128